# How to get primary keys for all tables in JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a database with at least 500 tables. What is the exact code to get all the primary keys and foreign keys of each table?

```
//Primary Key
DatabaseMetaData meta=conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs1= meta.getTables(null, null, "TableName" , new String[]{"TABLE"});
rs1=meta.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, "TableName");
while(rs1.next())
    System.out.println("Primary Key :"+rs1.getString(4));

//Foreign Key
rs1=meta.getExportedKeys(null, null, "TableName");
while(rs1.next())
    System.out.println("Foreign Key :"+rs1.getString(4));
```

I have used this code and it gives me accurate keys but for 500 tables, I have to change my code 500 times. Is there any way to minimize this effort?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to modify your code 500 times, you can retrieve all table names using `meta.getTables(null, null, "%", new String[]{"TABLE"})`.

The method `getTables` takes a like-pattern for the `tableNamePattern` parameter, so `"%"` matches all table names.

The method `getPrimaryKeys` and `getExportedKeys` do not take a pattern, so you will need to loop over the result of `getTables` and execute those methods for each row of the `getTables` result set.

So you will need to do something like:

```java
DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
try (ResultSet tables = meta.getTables(null, null, "%", new String[] { "TABLE" })) {
    while (tables.next()) {
        String catalog = tables.getString("TABLE_CAT");
        String schema = tables.getString("TABLE_SCHEM");
        String tableName = tables.getString("TABLE_NAME");
        System.out.println("Table: " + tableName);
        try (ResultSet primaryKeys = meta.getPrimaryKeys(catalog, schema, tableName)) {
            while (primaryKeys.next()) {
                System.out.println("Primary key: " + primaryKeys.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
            }
        }
        // similar for exportedKeys
    }
}
```

I have included retrieval of catalog and schema, because that might influence how things work.

Comment: Many thanks!
The Code for primary keys is working but for foreign keys, it is showing this error - 'The column name COLUMN_NAME is not valid.'
Kindly guide.

Comment: @KaushalDaga See the [java doc of `getExportedKeys`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getExportedKeys-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) You probably need to use `PKCOLUMN_NAME`.

Answer (score 4):

You can refer to this code snippet that shows you how to get all the tables from a database.

You need to iterate over your `ResultSet` calling next().

I have tried this for **MS SQL Server 2012**

```
public class RetrieveAllTables {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=HubDB", "sa", "password");
            DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
            ResultSet resultSet = databaseMetaData.getTables(null, null, "%", new String[] {"TABLE"});

            while(resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.print("Table Catalog: " + resultSet.getString("TABLE_CAT"));
                System.out.print("\tTable Schema: " + resultSet.getString("TABLE_SCHEM"));
                System.out.print("\tTable Name: " + resultSet.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Returns the following as output:

```
Table Catalog: HubDB    Table Schema: dbo   Table Name: films
Table Catalog: HubDB    Table Schema: dbo   Table Name: FILMS_AUDIT
Table Catalog: HubDB    Table Schema: sys   Table Name: trace_xe_action_map
Table Catalog: HubDB    Table Schema: sys   Table Name: trace_xe_event_map
```

Hence you need to change the following from

```
ResultSet resultSet = databaseMetaData.getTables(null, null, "%", new String[] {"TABLE"});
```

to

```
ResultSet resultSet = databaseMetaData.getTables(null, "dbo", "%", new String[] {"TABLE"});
```

You can refer the `getTables()` method documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29)

Using this information, you can dynamically pass the individual `TableName` to retrieve the `Primary Key` and the `Foreign Key` details. Your existing code should work just fine in retrieving these details by passing just one parameter, that's the `TableName` from the above code.