# How to find whether a column is "IDENTITY" column through java

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

For example let us say I have two mssql tables with the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE1(ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR);
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE2(ID INT, NAME VARCHAR);
```

I want to fetch the data in the table and if any column of any table is an IDENTITY column I want to do some operation. Is it possible to find out whether a column is identity column or not.

My requirement is like this

```
for(i=0;i<columns_list.length;i++){
      if(columns_list[i].isIDENTITY())
           //Do some stuff
      else
           //Do some other stuff
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40841078/how-to-get-primary-keys-for-all-tables-in-jdbc might help

Comment: Depends on your DBMS product and JDBC driver. In theory, [`DatabaseMetaData.getColumns()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) will return `IS_AUTOINCREMENT` and `IS_GENERATEDCOLUMN`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using MSSQL and JDBC 8

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam As far as I know primary key and IDENTITY can be two different columns will this still give the required result?

Comment: As far as I know, the [Microsoft JDBC driver](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc) returns this in `IS_AUTOINCREMENT`

Comment: Doesn't `IDENTITY` require two numerical arguments (seed and Increment)? `ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)` or is that optional?

Comment: I think its optional, table creation had no issues!!